# parsing quote and escape characters CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, text, import

I need to Import large sets of data into SQL, the output file (text) is UTC-8 generated from an ABAP program where I can define the quote and escape characters , by default I'm using :

`\` as escape string

`"` ( double quote) to quote characters

`;` (semi Colon) to separate the columns.

My problem resides that most of the columns which type is text contains double quotes or escape characters and when trying to import this into SQL database the interface fails because of data wrong allocation of the columns.

I manage to avoid the \n with below python scrip but I'm struggling with the Double quotes, Can you suggest any idea to replace the double quotes inside the quoting characters?

Text fields like  = banana from "Ecuador" its causing me a big mess since the data on the CSV file is stored as "banana from "Ecuador""

```
import csv
filename = "0180914_074626.csv"
with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as inputfile, \
     open(filename + '.log.csv', 'w', encoding="utf8") as outputfile_log:
     w = csv.writer(outputfile_log, delimiter=';', quotechar='"', lineterminator='\n')
       for record in csv.reader(inputfile):
            #print(record)
            w.writerow(tuple(s.replace("\n", '-') for s in record))
```

Comment: You would have to use different characters in your export for each of your delimiters (text qualifiers and column seperators).  I think column seperators wont matter once you fix issue with text qualifiers.  Try using a character you know wont exist in your data.  Or switch to tab or fixed width delimitors.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using [BCP with a Format File.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-a-format-file-to-bulk-import-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Then you can specify that, for example, the last column is terminated by a double-quote followed by a CRLF.   The other columns are terminated by double-quote followed by semi-colon.

For each column, any characters not matching the combination of characters that make up the terminator for that column will be ignored.